# Bean instantiation via constructor failed

Tags: java, vaadin, pom.xml, vaadin7, vaadin8

I just recently started to learn how to create a web app using vaadin with zero knowledge of web development. I've followed everything from the tutorial but I came out with an error. I'm stuck with this error for days and I really need help. This the error that I get when running the web app.

```
2020-09-14 14:12:53.351 ERROR 7016 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.v.flow.router.InternalServerError      : There was an exception while trying to navigate to ''

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.MainView': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanValidationBinder cannot be used because a JSR-303 Bean Validation implementation not found on the classpath or could not be initialized. Use Binder instead
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:294) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:117) ~[vaadin-spring-12.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:160) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:135) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:134) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.sendBeforeEnterEventAndPopulateChain(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:518) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.createChainIfEmptyAndExecuteBeforeEnterNavigation(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:498) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:230) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:249) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:220) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:186) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.initializeUI(Router.java:93) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.createAndInitUI(BootstrapHandler.java:1534) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:474) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1545) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247) ~[flow-server-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:108) ~[vaadin-spring-12.3.1.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanValidationBinder cannot be used because a JSR-303 Bean Validation implementation not found on the classpath or could not be initialized. Use Binder instead
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:217) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanValidationBinder cannot be used because a JSR-303 Bean Validation implementation not found on the classpath or could not be initialized. Use Binder instead
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.BeanValidationBinder.<init>(BeanValidationBinder.java:85) ~[flow-data-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.BeanValidationBinder.<init>(BeanValidationBinder.java:61) ~[flow-data-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.ContactForm.<init>(ContactForm.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.ui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
```

This is a line from the class mentioned in the error :

```
Binder<Contact>  binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(Contact.class);
```

Here I include some more code of that class.

```
    
public class ContactForm extends FormLayout {

    private Contact contact;
    TextField firstName = new TextField("First Name");
    TextField lastName = new TextField("Last Name");
    EmailField email = new EmailField("Email");
    ComboBox<Contact.Status> status = new ComboBox<>("Status");
    ComboBox<Company> company = new ComboBox<>("Company");

    Button save = new Button("Save");
    Button delete = new Button("Delete");
    Button close = new Button("Close");

    Binder<Contact>  binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(Contact.class);


    public ContactForm(List<Company> companies){
        addClassName("contact-form");
        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);

        company.setItems(companies);
        company.setItemLabelGenerator(Company::getName);
        status.setItems(Contact.Status.values());

        add(firstName,lastName,email,company,status,createButtonsLayout());
    }
```

Comment: The exception is pretty clear. You are using JSR-303 validation but only have the API in your `pom.xml` not an implementation like `hibernate-validator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaadin doesn't provide a built-in Bean Validation implementation - you need to supply one yourself in your project's dependencies. From [the docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder-beans.html#using-jsr-303-bean-validation):

> To use Bean Validation annotations, you need a JSR 303 implementation like Hibernate
> Validator available in your classpath. If your environment, such as Java EE container,
> does not provide the implementation, you can use the following dependency in Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ive did it. It worked when i added the dependency. After i add the dependency i only need to delete some jar file from the project folder. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency in pom.xml if using spring boot parent >2.3

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```